# Docusign capturing multiple signatures per document

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to duplicate the logic from this sample https://github.com/docusign/sample-app-loanco-nodejs/blob/master/routes/loan-sailboat.js in C#

I want to be able to capture two signatures for the same document (two different recipients), but am having trouble getting the second signature tab to show.

Here's a snippet:

```
 Signer signer1 = new Signer {
                Email = signerEmail,
                Name = signerName,
                ClientUserId = signerClientId,
                RecipientId = "1",
                RoutingOrder = "1"
            };

            Signer signer2 = new Signer
            {
                Email = "asdklfasdf@asdf.com",
                Name = "bobby boucher",
                ClientUserId = "2000",
                RecipientId = "2",
                RoutingOrder = "2"
            };

            // Create signHere fields (also known as tabs) on the documents,
            // We're using anchor (autoPlace) positioning
            //
            // The DocuSign platform seaches throughout your envelope's
            // documents for matching anchor strings.
            SignHere signHere1 = new SignHere
            {
                XPosition = "170",
                YPosition = "418",
                Optional = "false",
                StampType = "signature",
                DocumentId = "3",
                PageNumber = "1",
                RecipientId = "1",
                Name = "SignHere One",
            };
            SignHere signHere2 = new SignHere
            {
                XPosition = "200",
                YPosition = "418",
                Optional = "false",
                StampType = "signature",
                DocumentId = "3",
                PageNumber = "1",
                RecipientId = "2",
                Name = "SignHere Two"
            };
            // Tabs are set per recipient / signer
            Tabs signer1Tabs = new Tabs
            {
                SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere> { signHere1 }
            };
            signer1.Tabs = signer1Tabs;
            Tabs signer2Tabs = new Tabs
            {
                SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere> { signHere2 }
            };
            signer2.Tabs = signer2Tabs;

            // Add the recipient to the envelope object
            Recipients recipients = new Recipients
            {
                Signers = new List<Signer> { signer1, signer2 }
            };
            envelopeDefinition.Recipients = recipients;
```

**EDIT**: The solution is to create two view requests to capture two unique signatures on a document simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two signers, both with **ClientUserId** set, which means you create two views for them to both sign using embedded signing?
And after the first one signed, the second would sign.

This is probably the reason. If you want it done at the same time - set the **RoutingOrder** to both be "1".
If you want an email sent - remove the **ClientUserId**.

And of course, you need to two separate requests for the embedded signing - one for each signer.

Comment: This is for embedded signing. So would I set the **ClientUserId** to be the same for both signers? I tried modifying the properties in different combinations as well. Could I trouble you for a screenshare session? I think I have your email from last time.